# How to write test case for checking mail body in Laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, tdd

I have a controller where certain tasks are done along with a feature of sending mail to users. So wanted to write test cases for that as we were following TDD approach and we decided not to use mock for this purpose. Instead we used `Mail::fake()`. In my controller, I am queueing mail and using a mailable class to render my view and passing data to that mailable class. As a result, I cant check(in my test cases) the mail body or subject of that mailable class. Any idea on how to write test cases for checking mail body or any other best practices for that?

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel` has features to [assert](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mocking#mail-fake) that thecorrect [mail](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1bbe5528568555d597582fdbec73e31f8a818dbc/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php) is sent. You can get the subject by accessing the subject property and if you render the email into an view and render the view, you will get the email as a string and then make a string contains call on it.

```
Mail::assertSent(OrderShipped::class, function ($mail) {
    return $mail->subject === 'your subject' && 
        Str::contains($mail->render()->render(), 'Welcome to my website');
});
```

Comment: This comment is half pseudo code and i am not certain the mail->render()->render() is the best approach. If you have any problems write and i will look into it.

Comment: I think it will be assertQueued instead of assertSent. Anyway, that' not a big deal. The problem is with that $mail param. If I pass OrderShipped class as its first parameter I don't get any of its member's access trough the $mail object. As a result the $mail->subject results in null

Comment: Thats not how it works, you are checking if the class is OrderShipped and the mail that is actually sent, will be on the mail object, if its null i would argue it is not set in the email.